# Help Understanding Craft Email Settings

Tags: plugin-contactform, settings

I have a client who uses Office 365 for email.  Using the basic phpMail config in Craft fails when I try to direct an email to any of the clients email addresses, including user registration and, more importantly, when sending a message from the Contact Form plugin.

I have tried in vain to change the Craft email settings to SMTP, using credentials that have been tested with a desktop email client.  I am sure there is something I am missing, e.g. some server config thing.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Roi

Comment: What do you mean if fails?  Are you getting an error message or are they just not receiving the email? Or are you trying to use Office 365 as the SMTP server to relay?

Comment: Getting an error.  I think the problem is rooted in the fact that the client's hosting account (Bluehost) is on a shared IP and, therefore, does not have access to "certain server features".  I set up the exact same scenario on my site (hosted by Arcustech) and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It could be your server blocks outgoing mail on the default port (25). Try port 587 instead.

Comment: Thanks, Bob.  I did use 587, but no luck